# How to read the notation used for the swap rates in the form 4.412/452 for the 1 year swap rate?

Tags: derivatives, swaps, interest-rate-swap

How to read the notation used for the swap rates in Table 20.6 below?
What does 2.412/452 means?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is 2.412 bid, 2.452 offered.  A 4bp wide market.

Comment: If you want to receive fixed you will receive 2.412, if you want to pay fixed you will have to pay 2.452